# How do I close AlertDialog when I click on ListView item

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, alert

Here is my dialog code, there is a `ListView` in a dialog, I wanna close this dialog when I click on `ListView`:

```
public void createSearchDialog(final String[] Memo){
        LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View searchView = factory.inflate(R.layout.seach_dialog, null);

            lv = (ListView) searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_list);
        lv.setAdapter(new MyPerformanceArrayAdapter(this, Memo, memo_PW));
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                         /// close dialog
            }
        });


        searchBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        searchBuilder.setTitle("Search")
               .setView(searchView)
               .setNegativeButton("Back", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {               
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            })
               .show();     

    }
```

I tried to put this code in `onItemClick()`

```
    searchBuilder.create().dismiss();

    searchBuilder.create().cancel();
```

But it's not working.

Comment: an AlertDialog auto closes on the click of a button BY DEFAULT.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Change `.show()` to `dialog = searchBuilder.show();` then put `dialog.dismiss()` to `onItemClick()`.

Comment: where to initialize dialog and what is the type and how to use it .. kindly give proper answer with code..

Comment: AlertDialog dialog; would be global then it will work

Answer (score 2):

**Complete Code For this problem**

```
 public void showDialog(){
    final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    dialog.setTitle("Choose App");
    dialog.setCancelable(true);

    View view = ((Activity)getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_all_app, null);
    list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.AllAppList);
    AllAppPckName = getPackages();
    AllAppListAdapter adapter= new AllAppListAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.app_item, AllAppPckName);

    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            appIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            appIcon.setImageDrawable(getPackageIcon(getContext(), AllAppPckName.get(i)));
            appNameBtn.setText(getAppNameFromPkgName(getContext(), AllAppPckName.get(i)));

            dialogg.dismiss();


        }
    });


    dialog.setView(view);
    dialogg = dialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For dismissing the dialog `.dismiss()` will work. Please check you are calling this in proper place. if you want to close the dialog when a selection is made from your `ListView` then you need to dismiss the dialog in the action listener of your `ListView`.

Comment: i put searchBuilder.create().dismiss(); into onItemClick but it's still not work

Comment: can u try with searchbuilder.dismiss()

Comment: i can't call searchbuilder.dismiss()  , ,The method dismiss() is undefined for the type AlertDialog.Builder